# download option in repeater table

Tags: c#, asp.net

when user upload any document then this document go for approval when this document approve then user able to download to download other vise not

this is want i done

```
           doc id doc name file uplaoded uploaded date department       status 
   download       1    analysis  abc.docx    12-12-2013   finance        approve
   download      2    report fm  fm.docx    14-06-2013   finance         reject
  download      3    report ibf  ibf.docx    14-06-2013   finance         approve
   download      4    report ma  ma.docx    14-06-2013   finance         reject
```

and this is what i want

```
            doc id doc name file uplaoded uploaded date department       status 
   download       1    analysis  abc.docx    12-12-2013   finance        approve
                 2    report fm  fm.docx    14-06-2013   finance         reject
  download       3    report ibf  ibf.docx    14-06-2013   finance         approve
                 4    report ma  ma.docx    14-06-2013   finance         reject
```

now in reject row i don't want to show download option because this is rejected documents 
here  is download code

```
  protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "download")
        {
            string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            string path = MapPath("~/Docfiles/" + filename);
            byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
            filename);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }


    }
```

html

```
            <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                          id="results">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" 
                       runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Document ID
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Document Name
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    File Uploaded
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Uploaded Date
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Document Type
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Department Type
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approve Name
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   
                             CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileUploaded") 
                                %>'                                              
             CommandName="download">Download</asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>                                            
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocumentID") %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                           "DocumentName")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                   "FileUploaded")%>
                                </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                        "UploadedDate")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                        "Document")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                     "Department")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

how i done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are binding to a data source and do not have server controls within your repeater's markup for the text you want to check, then you will need to use the `DataRowView` object inside of the `ItemDataBound` event, like this:

```
DataRowView theDataRowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
```

Now you can reference your data by the binding value you used in your markup, like this:

```
theDataRowView.Row["Status"] == "some value"
```

So your `ItemDataBound` event should now look like this:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Only look in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        // Get a data view row object so we can reference the data 
        // in the repeater by the bound field names      
        DataRowView theDataRowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

        // Make sure we got the data row view before we try to use it
        if(theDataRowView != null)
        {
            // Get the value of status from the control that holds the value
            string theStatus = theDataRowView.Row["Status"];

            // Find the download link control
            LinkButton theLinkButtonDownload = e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;

            if(theStatus.ToLower() == "approve")
            {
                if(theLinkButtonDownload != null)
                {
                    theLinkButtonDownload.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(theLinkButtonDownload != null)
                {
                    theLinkButtonDownload.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code where i add if(theDataRowView.Row["Status"] == "status")
{

}  in html or in above repeater1_itemdatabound???

Comment: where i add this code   if(theDataRowView.Row["Status"] == "status") { } in html or in above repeater1_itemdatabound  in html or in item databound

Comment: @user2931015 - I have updated the answer, I was speaking generally about how to use the `DataRowView.Row` object. The code I posted in the answer uses the following `if(theStatus.ToLower() == "approve")`, where `theStatus` was retrieved from the `DataRowView` object like this: `string theStatus = theDataRowView.Row["Status"];`. Sorry for the confusion.