# document name downloable in repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, download

When user uploads document then his/her document goes for approval to the supervsior, and his document appear in repeater. Then I want this document name downloadable. When admin click on document name then it will be downloaded. How I have done this:

Here is html markup:

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="results">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand"   
        runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>

               <%-- <td>
                   DocumentID
                </td>--%>
                <td>
                   Document Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    File Name
                </td>
                <td>
                   Uploaded By
                </td>
                <td>
                   Uploaded Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>

                <td>
                    Department
                </td>
                <td>
                    Status

                </td>

            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="DocId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>' />

                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="DocName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="Uploadfile" runat="server"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uploadfile")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="Label1" runat="server"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UploadedBy")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="UploadedDate" runat="server"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UploadedDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="YourEamil" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserEmail")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Id="DepType" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDepartmentId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown1" DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting the files information from a table? If it's like that you could use in the item template (not in the head template)
<div>DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentName")</div> <asp:Button runat = "server" Text = "Download" ID = "btnDownload" CommandName = "Download"/> 
You can leave the OnItemCommand and check the command name in code behind
But you'll need to load that template only when an admin is entering the page

Comment: Did you look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202160/download-option-in-repeater-table?rq=1) ?

Comment: this is download option ... but here i want the document name able to clickable and when click on document name it must be download have a look this picture please...  http://i59.tinypic.com/65r71s.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `<a>` element in the admin page and provide file path into `href=""` where 
he uploads document.Than admin can download document from given `<a>` link.

This approach can also provide history of Uploads Documents.